# Is it ok to call model learning in machine learning an "estimator"?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, terminology

[Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/ml-guide.html#estimators) contains this:

> An Estimator abstracts the concept of a learning algorithm or any algorithm that fits or trains on data. Technically, an Estimator implements a method fit(), which accepts a DataFrame and produces a Model, which is a Transformer. For example, a learning algorithm such as LogisticRegression is an Estimator, and calling fit() trains a LogisticRegressionModel, which is a Model and hence a Transformer.

But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator#Background) says:

> An "estimator" or "point estimate" is a statistic (that is, a function of the data) that is used to infer the value of an unknown parameter in a statistical model. The parameter being estimated is sometimes called the estimand. It can be either finite-dimensional (in parametric and semi-parametric models), or infinite-dimensional (semi-parametric and non-parametric models). If the parameter is denoted $\theta$ then the estimator is traditionally written by adding a circumflex over the symbol: $\widehat {\theta }$. Being a function of the data, the estimator is itself a random variable; a particular realization of this random variable is called the "estimate". Sometimes the words "estimator" and "estimate" are used interchangeably.

I would have called the machine learning model itself the "estimator". Are the 2 definitions above close enough, or off, or are there important distinctions to be aware of?

Comment: This is part of the problem between CS/ML people and stats. There's a difference in language. What they mean by Estimator is more of a method/implementation not a point estimate.

Comment: @Jon you are confusing estimator (a function) with estimate (it's outcome given the sample), see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/what-is-the-relation-between-estimator-and-estimate

Comment: What else would you call something that estimates the parameters of the model?

Comment: @david25272 - a procedure, algorithm, method, recipe... for the part that does the calculation of the parameters of the model?

Comment: I've always thought of algorithms as specific (e.g. OLS, Iteratively Reweighted LS) examples of estimators.

Comment: I don't think so. You can estimate parameters for a model using estimation. I see estimation as a type of inference.

Answer (score 8):

Spark's documentation refers to internal names of Spark's procedures and objects, not to theoretical concepts. In statistics [*estimator* is basically a procedure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/what-is-the-relation-between-estimator-and-estimate) that *estimates* something given the data and returns an *estimate*.

It is hard to answer your question without knowing what you mean by *model*. [Statistical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model) describes the phenomenon of interest [in terms of probability theory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243746/what-is-probabilistic-inference/243759#243759) (notice that there are also other models, e.g. [mechanistic models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34231/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mechanistic-and-a-statistical-predictive-model)). It is not yet an estimator of anything, but just an abstract description of the problem. You need an estimator to estimate the parameters of your model (also in case of so-called non-parametric models). In machine learning people often call *algorithms* used to estimate something as models, but in general: *model* is a theoretical description of the problem and *estimator* is a procedure that generates the *estimates* of its parameters. Estimator is a general procedure, not its implementation, so function `foo()` in software XYZ is not an estimator, but rather it's an implementation of some estimator.

Comment: (+1) My understanding was that statistical models - which have a stochastic & deterministic component - comprise mechanistic models & empirical models. The form of the deterministic component of the former is decided by theory; that of the latter by how much flexibility it seems prudent to allow - representing predictors with a polynomial, spline, fourier term, &c. basis.